# How to pass multiple integers to ManyToMany Field present in the list in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I want add this product to both  category, how to do it

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='categories', default='default.png')

class Products(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    category_id = models.ManyToManyField(Category, default='')
```

```
category_id = [4, 6]

 product, created = Products.objects.get_or_create(name =data['Casual Red Shirt'], 
                              product.category_id.add()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
category_id = [4, 6]
product, created  = Products.objects.get_or_create(name =data['Casual Red Shirt'], 

product.category_id.add(* category_id)
```